# python bs4 ignore crawl mailto links

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, mailto

i am trying since yesterday to find out to ignoring 'mailto://' and 'mailto:' links with beautifulsoup and requests.

my code:

```
    for link in links:
        if not link.startswith('mailto://'):
            if not link.startswith('mailto:'):
                if total_urls_visited > max_urls:
                    break
                crawl(link, max_urls=max_urls)
                if not link.startswith('GET'):
                    continue
                elif link.endswith(ignore_list): #use ignore directly here
                    continue
                else:
                    print(link)
```

but in same of webpages by crawling i am getting error like this one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/Desktop/site_crawler/get_all_links.py", line 175, in <module>
    reqs = requests.get(internal_link, headers=headers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 59, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 587, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 695, in send
    adapter = self.get_adapter(url=request.url)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 792, in get_adapter
    raise InvalidSchema(f"No connection adapters were found for {url!r}")
requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema: No connection adapters were found for 'mailto://info@mail.app
```

can't find out why is it not working...
is there an easy way or any idea?

thanks.

EDIT:

@Ofer
trying all options but it doesn't help. crawl is crawling all internal_urls in given domain name.

@Michael:
on line 175 I have:

```
content_type = reqs.headers.get('content-type')
```

Comment: why so many nested `if` statements? what does `crawl` do?

Comment: The cause of the error is the topmost entry in the traceback in this case. The code around this should be shown in the question.

Answer (score 1):

While you didn't confirm the url, here is a clearcut example of how you can get all links from a webpage, and separate 'mailto' links from the others:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.foxnews.com/'

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
links = soup.select('a')
good_links = [x.get('href') for x in soup.select('a') if 'mailto' not in x.get('href')]
bad_links = [x.get('href') for x in soup.select('a') if 'mailto' in x.get('href')]
print(bad_links)
print(good_links)
```

This will return:

```
['mailto:adsales@foxnews.com?subject=Advertising%20Inquiry', 'mailto:adsales@foxnews.com?subject=Advertising%20Inquiry']
['https://www.foxnews.com', 'https://www.foxnews.com/us', 'https://www.foxnews.com/politics', 'https://www.foxnews.com/media', 'https://www.foxnews.com/opinion', ...]
```

Comment: hi platipus_on_fire and thanks for your example.
I tried to change your given code on https://github.com/x4nth055/pythoncode-tutorials/blob/master/web-scraping/link-extractor/link_extractor.py this example, I couldn't do it. Do you have any idea how I can pass the mailto:// links?

Comment: I would imagine you include the logic in the code above into `is_valid(url)` function, in that  complex scraping construct @mhmtbsbyndr